# Cifra de césar, Erro no deslocamento das letras

Tags: c

Estou tentando fazer um programa que, o usuário vai digitar um nome e vai ser pedido quantas posições o usuário deseja deslocar para a direita. Porém, tive um problema. Se eu digitar a letra A e deslocar a 10 posições, aparecerá o número 7, teria como eu resolver isso?

O meu código

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  char nome[100];
  int teste, i;
  printf("Informe um nome:\n");
  scanf("%s", nome);
  printf("Voce quer deslocar a quantas posicoes para a direita:\n");
  scanf("%d", &teste);
  for(i = 0; i < strlen(nome); i++)
  {
     nome[i] = nome[i] - teste;
  }
    printf("%s\n", nome);
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para deslocar para a direita tem de somar ao invés de subtrair. Ainda assim o problema persiste, que é de chegar ao limite do alfabeto e começar a apanhar outros carateres da tabela ASCII que não letras do abecedário. Tem que detetar quando isso acontece para poder calcular a letra correta fazendo uma rotação:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define TAM_ALFABETO 26 //tamanho do alfabeto definido aqui

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    char nome[100];
    int teste, i;
    printf("Informe um nome:\n");
    scanf("%s", nome);
    printf("Voce quer deslocar a quantas posicoes para a direita:\n");
    scanf("%d", &teste);

    for(i = 0; i < strlen(nome); i++) {
        if (nome[i] >= 'a' && nome[i] <= 'z'){ //se é minuscula
            nome[i] = (nome[i] + teste - 'a') % TAM_ALFABETO + 'a';
        }
        else {//se é maiúscula
            nome[i] = (nome[i] + teste - 'A') % TAM_ALFABETO + 'A';
        }
    }

    printf("%s\n", nome);
    return 0;
}
```

Tentando detalhar a instrução que modifica a letra:

```
nome[i] = (nome[i] + teste - 'a') % TAM_ALFABETO + 'a';
```

- Pega na letra e soma a quantidade de posições (o nome `teste` para a quantidade de posições não foi de facto o melhor)
- Subtrai `'a'` para ficar com um numero entre `0` e `26`
- Faz modulo sobre o tamanho do alfabeto para nunca passar esse tamanho
- Volta a somar `'a'` para ficar com uma letra entre `'a'` e `'z'`

Vejamos o mesmo exemplo para a letra `'z'` e aumento `3`:

- `'z'(122)` + `3` dá `'}'(125)`
- Subtrai `'a'(97)` que vai dar `28`
- `28 % 26` dá `2`
- `2 + 'a'` dá `'c'`

Por isso `z` com aumento de `3` dá `c`

[Veja o código a funcionar no Ideone](https://ideone.com/XzzCcw)

Outra alternativa é construir um array de chars com todas as letras válidas e fazer a rotação com base nesse array. Isso de certa forma simplifica a logica da rotação.